# Error: Cannot find package '@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node-modules, babel-loader

I hope you're all fine !

I have tried rake assets:clobber in my app but everything went wrong since then. I first got a no manifest.json error and I tried to update everything I could. And now here is what I have :

```
Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Cannot find package '@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods' imported from /Users/XXX/code/xxx/xxx/babel-virtual-resolve-base.js
    at __node_internal_ (/Users/XXX/code/xxx/xxx/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/vendor/import-meta-resolve.js:233:9)
    at new NodeError (/Users/XXX/code/xxx/xxx/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/vendor/import-meta-resolve.js:203:5)
    at packageResolve (/Users/XXX/code/xxx/xxx/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/vendor/import-meta-resolve.js:873:9)
    at moduleResolve (/Users/XXX/code/xxx/xxx/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/vendor/import-meta-resolve.js:902:20)
    at defaultResolve (/Users/XXX/code/xxx/xxx/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/vendor/import-meta-resolve.js:985:15)
    at resolve (/Users/XXX/code/xxx/xxx/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/vendor/import-meta-resolve.js:999:12)
    at tryImportMetaResolve (/Users/XXX/code/xxx/xxx/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:137:45)
    at resolveStandardizedNameForImport (/Users/XXX/code/xxx/xxx/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:159:19)
    at resolveStandardizedName (/Users/XXX/code/xxx/xxx/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:168:12)
    at loadPlugin (/Users/XXX/code/xxx/xxx/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:47:20)
    at loadPlugin.next (<anonymous>)
    at createDescriptor (/Users/XXX/code/xxx/xxx/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:140:16)
    at createDescriptor.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/Users/XXX/code/xxx/xxx/node_modules/gensync/index.js:261:32)
    at evaluateAsync (/Users/XXX/code/xxx/xxx/node_modules/gensync/index.js:291:5)
    at /Users/XXX/code/xxx/xxx/node_modules/gensync/index.js:44:11
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Function.async (/Users/XXX/code/xxx/xxx/node_modules/gensync/index.js:43:15)
    at Function.all (/Users/XXX/code/xxx/xxx/node_modules/gensync/index.js:216:13)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at createDescriptors (/Users/XXX/code/xxx/xxx/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:102:41)
    at createDescriptors.next (<anonymous>)
    at createPluginDescriptors (/Users/XXX/code/xxx/xxx/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:99:17)
    at createPluginDescriptors.next (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/XXX/code/xxx/xxx/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/gensync-utils/functional.js:21:23
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at mergeChainOpts (/Users/XXX/code/xxx/xxx/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:350:34)
    at mergeChainOpts.next (<anonymous>)
    at chainWalker (/Users/XXX/code/xxx/xxx/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:317:14)
    at chainWalker.next (<anonymous>)
    at loadFileChain (/Users/XXX/code/xxx/xxx/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:192:24)
    at loadFileChain.next (<anonymous>)
    at buildRootChain (/Users/XXX/code/xxx/xxx/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:78:27)
    at buildRootChain.next (<anonymous>)
    at loadPrivatePartialConfig (/Users/XXX/code/xxx/xxx/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/partial.js:72:62)
    at loadPrivatePartialConfig.next (<anonymous>)
    at loadPartialConfig (/Users/XXX/code/xxx/xxx/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/partial.js:115:25)
    at loadPartialConfig.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/Users/XXX/code/xxx/xxx/node_modules/gensync/index.js:269:25)
    at evaluateAsync (/Users/XXX/code/xxx/xxx/node_modules/gensync/index.js:291:5)
    at /Users/XXX/code/xxx/xxx/node_modules/gensync/index.js:93:9
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at async (/Users/XXX/code/xxx/xxx/node_modules/gensync/index.js:92:14)
    at stopHiding - secret - don't use this - v1 (/Users/XXX/code/xxx/xxx/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/errors/rewrite-stack-trace.js:47:12)
    at loadPartialConfigAsync (/Users/XXX/code/xxx/xxx/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/index.js:34:85)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/XXX/code/xxx/xxx/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:126:26)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/Users/XXX/code/xxx/xxx/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:3:103)
    at _next (/Users/XXX/code/xxx/xxx/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:4:194)
    at /Users/XXX/code/xxx/xxx/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:4:364
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/XXX/code/xxx/xxx/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:4:97)
    at Object._loader (/Users/XXX/code/xxx/xxx/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:210:18)
    at Object.loader (/Users/XXX/code/xxx/xxx/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:48:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/XXX/code/xxx/xxx/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:44:12)
```

and my package.json

```
  "name": "XXX",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.18.6",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.7",
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/actiontext": "^6.0.6-1",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "5.4.4",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.11.1",
    "stimulus": "^3.2.2",
    "stimulus-notification": "^2.2.0",
    "stimulus-use": "^0.52.0",
    "trix": "^1.2.0",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.23.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.2",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-private-methods": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.2",
    "@babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3"
  }
}
```

I have tried to "yarn add @babel/plugin-transform-private-methods --dev"
but I get :

```
yarn add v1.22.19
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@babel-loader: Request \"https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@babel-loader\" returned a 405".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/xxx/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

Any idea ? Need more info ?
Thanks a lot in advance !
Jay